# How do i use a variable defined in a function in another function?

Tags: function, variables, global

```
def number():
   win = 1
   return win
```

I want to call the varialble win up again in another function.

```
def callwin():
   if win == 1:
   return True
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to move variable out of function scope:

```
win = 1;

def number():
   return win

def callwin():
    if win == 1:
    return True
```

Comment: If I failed with this python-like syntax, feel free to correct.